# PowerShell Script to Replace non-HTML Tags

Tags: regex, powershell, windows-scripting

I'm working on a PowerShell script that aims to find lines in HTML files containing angle brackets not belonging to HTML tags. The script should replace said angle brackets with `&lt;` and `&gt;`.  However, I'm facing difficulties with the current script and the replacement logic seems to be not working as intended. It's worth noting that I'm operating on markdown files and I need to do this using **Powershell version 5.1.22621.2428** without including anything from the outside.

To simplify the script, these are the requirements I posed as necessary for a tag to be interpreted as such:

- Any tag must be closed. For example, `<hello>` will be a valid tag, while `<hello` won't. It doesn't matter if there is a space after the first word, because otherwise tags with properties won't be detected properly.
- There mustn't be any spaces between the opening tag and first word. For example, `< hello>` won't be a tag, while `<hello>` or `<hello >` will. This is to prevent something like `3 < 4 > 2` to be interpreted as a valid tag.
- The tag has to have something inside. For example, `<>` won't be a valid tag.
- A tag must not start with a number.

Here's the test markdown file I've been using to test these scripts:

```
<
text
>
<ul>
   <li>[Message processing time] < [time to send ack to Azure Service Bus] (about less than 100ms per message)</li>
   <li>[Total process time of a group of messages] < [Message Lock Time] (default: 1 min)<br><b>Strictly REQUIRED</b> to avoid lock loss and messages processed more than one time
   </li>
</ul>
<>
> <
5 > 3 < 2 > 1

<a href="www.google.com">placeholder!!</a>

<hello >
< ciao>
<hello>
<hello></hello>
</b>
< /b>
```

Whose correct output should be:

```
&lt;
text
&gt;
<ul>
   <li>[Message processing time] &lt; [time to send ack to Azure Service Bus] (about less than 100ms per message)</li>
   <li>[Total process time of a group of messages] &lt; [Message Lock Time] (default: 1 min)<br><b>Strictly REQUIRED</b> to avoid lock loss and messages processed more than one time
   </li>
</ul>
&lt;&gt;
&gt; &lt;
5 &gt; 3 &lt; 2 &gt; 1

<a href="www.google.com">placeholder!!</a>

<hello >
&lt; hello&gt;
<hello></hello>
</b>
&lt; /b&gt;
```

## What I've tried

I've tried a couple of different approaches.
In the first attempt, I used a plain Powershell script, as required by the circumstances. This is the script I'm trying to fix.

This works great with tags alone, but when they are nested one inside another it breaks apart.
Here is an example text for demonstration purposes:

```
<
text
>
<ul>
   <li>[Message processing time] < [time to send ack to Azure Service Bus] (about less than 100ms per message)</li>
   <li>[Total process time of a group of messages] < [Message Lock Time] (default: 1 min)<br><b>Strictly REQUIRED</b> to avoid lock loss and messages processed more than one time
   </li>
</ul>
<>
> <
5 > 3 < 2 > 1

<a href="www.google.com">placeholder!!</a>
```

Which is translated into:

```
&lt;
text
&gt;
<ul>
   &lt;li&gt;[Message processing time] &lt; [time to send ack to Azure Service Bus] (about less than 100ms per message)&lt;/li&gt;
   &lt;li&gt;[Total process time of a group of messages] &lt; [Message Lock Time] (default: 1 min)&lt;br&gt;&lt;b&gt;Strictly REQUIRED&lt;/b&gt; to avoid lock loss and messages processed more than one time
   </li>
</ul>
<>
&gt; &lt;
5 &gt; 3 &lt; 2 &gt; 1

<a href="www.google.com">placeholder!!</a>
```

Here's the code:

```
function find-nonHTMLtags($files) {
    foreach ($file in $files) {
        try {
            # Read the content of the file
            $content = Get-Content -Path $file.FullName -Raw

            # Process each line
            $modifiedContent = foreach ($line in $content -split '\r?\n') {
                # Replace < with &lt; if it is not part of a closed HTML tag or has a space after it
                if ($line -notmatch '<\s*(?:[^>]+)?>' -or $line -match '<\s') {
                    $line = $line -replace '<', '&lt;'
                }

                # Replace > with &gt; if it is not part of a closed HTML tag
                if ($line -notmatch '<\s*(?:[^>]+)?>') {
                    $line = $line -replace '>', '&gt;'
                }

                # Output the modified line or the original line if no changes were made
                $line
            }

            # Join the modified lines into the modified content
            $modifiedContent = $modifiedContent -join "`r`n"

            # Check if both $content and modified content are non-empty before determining modification
            if (-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($content) -and $content -ne $modifiedContent) {
                # Write the modified content back to the file
                $modifiedContent | Set-Content -Path $file.FullName -Encoding UTF8
                Write-Host "Changed non-HTML tag(s) at: $($file.FullName)"
            }
        }
        catch {
            Write-Host "`nCouldn't changed non-HTML tag(s) at: $($file.FullName). $_"
        }
    }
}

$mdFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File -Recurse -Filter '*.md'
find-nonHTMLtags $mdFiles
```

The second approach I've tried is using [HAP](https://html-agility-pack.net/) through the .dll file. This works great, but sadly I've been told I can't use such files since they could pose a security threat.
Here's the code anyway:

```
param (
    $path
)

function ReplaceSymbols($files) {
    foreach ($file in $files) {
        try {
            $content = Get-Content -Path $file.FullName -Raw

            Add-Type -Path (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot 'HtmlAgilityPack.dll')

            $htmlDocument = New-Object HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
            $htmlDocument.LoadHtml($content)

            # Iterate through each HTML node
            foreach ($node in $htmlDocument.DocumentNode.DescendantsAndSelf()) {
                # Check if the node is text
                if ($node.NodeType -eq 'Text') {
                    # Replace < with &lt; and > with &gt; only in text nodes
                    $node.InnerHtml = $node.InnerHtml -replace '<', '&lt;' -replace '>', '&gt;'
                }
            }

            if (-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($content) -and $content -ne $htmlDocument.DocumentNode.OuterHtml) {
                $htmlDocument.DocumentNode.OuterHtml | Set-Content -Path $file.FullName -Encoding UTF8
                Write-Host "File content modified: $($file.FullName)"
            }
        }
        catch {
            Write-Host "Error modifying file content: $($file.FullName). $_"
        }
    }
}

$mdFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File -Recurse -Include '*.md'
Write-Host "Markdown Files Count $($mdFiles.Count)"
ReplaceSymbols $filesToProcess
```

Another approach which works is using Javascript with NodeJS, but sadly I cannot use this approach either since NodeJS is not supported.
Code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

function replaceNonHTMLtags(files) {
    files.forEach(filePath => {
        try {
            const content = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');

            String.prototype.replaceAt = function (index, char) {
                let arr = this.split('');
                arr[index] = char;
                return arr.join('');
            };
            
            String.prototype.escape = function () {
                let p = /(?:<[a-zA-Z]+\s*[^>]*>)|(?:<\/[a-zA-Z]+>)|(?<lt><)|(?<gt>>)/g,
                result = this,
                match = p.exec(result);
            
                while (match !== null) {
                    if (match.groups.lt !== undefined) {
                        result = result.replaceAt(match.index, '&lt;');
                    } else if (match.groups.gt !== undefined) {
                        result = result.replaceAt(match.index, '&gt;');
                    }
                    match = p.exec(result);
                }
                return result;
            };
            
            

            // Perform modifications on the content
            const modifiedContent = content.escape();

            // Check if both content and modifiedContent aren't empty before doing anything else
            if (content !== '' && content !== modifiedContent) {
                // Write the modified content back to the file
                fs.writeFileSync(filePath, modifiedContent, 'utf8');
                console.log(`Edited: ${modifiedContent}`);
                console.log(`Edited: ${filePath}`);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`Couldn't edit: ${filePath}. ${error.message}`);
        }
    });
}

const dynamicPath = ''; // Empty to use only __dirname
const orderFiles = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, dynamicPath)).filter(file => file.endsWith('.md')).map(file => path.join(dynamicPath, file));

console.log(`Markdown Files Count: ${orderFiles.length}`);
replaceNonHTMLtags(orderFiles);
```

Comment: Here is a pattern for _start tags_, `(?i)<[a-z]+(?:\s+[^>]+|\s*)>`, and a pattern for _end tags_, `(?i)</[a-z]+\s*>`.  It's worth noting, the _HTML5 specification_ includes documentation for writing a parser; _section 8.2_.  And, the _Google Chrome_ browser, provides an _open-source_ project, called _Chromium_.  You can traverse their implementation, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As any [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based HTML processing, the following [*isn't fully robust*](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/), but may work in your case:

```
$modifiedContent = 
  (Get-Content -Raw $file) `
    -replace '<(?!(?:/\s*)?[a-z]+(?:\s+[^>]*)?/?>)',  '&lt;' `
    -replace '(?<!<(?:/\s*)?[a-z]+(?:\s+[^>]*)?/?)>', '&gt;'
```

The gist of the approach is to use a negative look-*ahead* assertion (`(?!…)`) to make sure that what follows `<` isn't the rest of an HTML tag, and, analogously, a negative look-*behind* assertion (`(?<!…)`) to ensure that what precedes `>` isn't the start of one.

For a detailed explanation of the regexes and the option to experiment with them, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/qDh2NT/2); for simplicity, the two regexes have been merged into a single one with alternation (`|`), with a *placeholder* replacement string, `&[gl]t;` to symbolize the two distinct replacements in the code above, `&gt;` and `&lt;`